# Iterate increasing values in two lists

Tags: python, loops

I have two lists:

```
a = [0, 3, 5, 6, 10, 14]
b = [2, 4, 8, 9, 12, 17]
```

I would like to iterate over both at the same time in alternating steps and deal with the values in increasing order. So if we were printing each value they would be in this order:

0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 17

I've messed around with it, trying things like:

```
i = 0
j = 0
while i < len(a) or j < len(b):
    if a[i] < b[j]:
        print a[i]
        i += 1
    elif b[j] < a[i]:
        print b[j]
        j += 1
```

but this results in a keyerror at the end of one of the lists.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice. Are you learning Python? If so why are you learning Python 2? It hit end of life in January.

Comment: Look at [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge). For example `print(*heapq.merge(a, b), sep=', ')`

Comment: What if two values are equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `and` instead of `or` and afterwards print whatever's remaining:

```
while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
    ...
k, remaining = (i, a) if i < len(a) else (j, b)
for x in remaining[k:]:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine them and then sort the result:

```
c = sorted(a + b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `zip` is what you want

```
for aa ,bb in zip(a, b):
    print(f'{aa},{bb}')
```

Comment: That's what I thought too at first, but in the desired output it goes 5, 6, 8 instead of 5, 8, 6.

Comment: You can sort the results

Comment: You mean something like `aa, bb = sorted(aa, bb)`? That wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: above, `sorted(a + b)`. I was answering how to iterate over two lists at the sametime

Answer (score 0):

As [Andrej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552792/iterate-increasing-values-in-two-lists/61552984#comment108881254_61552792), you can use [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) instead:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> print(*heapq.merge(a, b))
0 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 12 14 17
```